# Is it possible to use in a Rakefile tasks from another one?

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile

I have some Rake tasks I'd like to use in my Rakefiles. Is it possible to include tasks defined in one rakefile from another rakefile?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rake files are nothing different than ruby files.
So just load the file A containing the other tasks in your file B and they will be available when B is executed.

For instance, if you put the following code in your Rakefile

```
Dir['tasks/*.rake'].each { |file| load(file) }
```

then you can create as many `.rake` files in the `tasks` subfolder and call them from the main `Rakefile`.

Comment: Yup. I always do this, to a) keep to one domain per file (all gem related tasks in `gem.rake`, all test related tasks in `test.rake`, all documentation related tasks in `doc.rake`) and b) share common tasks between different projects (calling RDoc, RSpec, RubyGems is really the same, independent of the specific project).

Answer (score 2):

I've just done something similar with the following:

```
task :master do
  `rake slave`
end

task :slave do
  puts "Hello World"
end
```

Perhaps a little rudimentary, but it does the job.

Comment: I believe this strategy, while possibly working, is not ideal. Try instead: `Rake::Task[:'slave'].invoke` for the master task.